# how to include double quotes into a ccnet property?

Tags: properties, cruisecontrol.net

i want to define a property in CCNET like that

```
    <cb:define build.any.args = "/p:Configuration=SkipTestsRelease;Platform=Any CPU /v:n" />
```

but i need to quote the "Platform=Any CPU" part.

how can i include the double quotes into that property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&quot;` instead of `"` :

```
<cb:define build.any.args = "/p:Configuration=SkipTestsRelease;&quot;Platform=Any CPU&quot; /v:n" />
```

[source](http://build.nauck-it.de/doc/CCNET/Configuration%20Preprocessor.html)